# Programatically position ImageView in the center of the screen

Tags: android

I would like to programatically position ImageView in the center of the screen.
In xml, ImageView is positioned in top left corner. I tried to do it in xml, but it was not possible due to some reasons.
ImageView width is 200dp, and height is 220dp.

This is what I have for now:

```
        DisplayMetrics dm = getApplicationContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
        float dpHeight = dm.heightPixels / dm.density;
        float dpWidth = dm.widthPixels / dm.density;

        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) imageView.getLayoutParams();
        lp.leftMargin = lp.leftMargin + (int) ((dpWidth / 2) - 100);
        lp.topMargin = lp.topMargin + (int) ((dpHeight / 2) - 110);
```

Comment: Did you get any solution?

Answer (score 2):

To do it programatically, you can do it like this.

```
// get the center point of the screen
Point point = new Point();
WindowManager manager = (WindowManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
manager.getDefaultDisplay().getSize(point);

int centerX = point.x / 2;
int centerY = point.y / 2;

// set the imageview minus half the width and height so its centered
imageview.setTranslationX(centerX - (imageview.getWidth() / 2));
imageview.setTranslationY(centerY - (imageview.getHeight() / 2));
```

Comment: ImageView disappeared from the screen with this code.

Comment: maybe you can try it with setTranslationX, setTranslationY

Answer (score 2):

Finally I get the result by programmatic way,

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/RL"
>


<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/IV"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/faleavatar"

     />
```

Now goto your Java Page

```
 ImageView iv=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.IV);

    DisplayMetrics metrics = getResources().getDisplayMetrics();

    int DeviceTotalWidth = metrics.widthPixels;
    int DeviceTotalHeight = metrics.heightPixels;

    RelativeLayout RelativeLayoutImageCenter=(RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.RL);
    RelativeLayoutImageCenter.setPadding(DeviceTotalWidth/4,DeviceTotalHeight/4,0,0);
```

Comment: I tried this, and around 1/3 of screen from top and around 1/4 of the screen from the left is white.

Answer (score 1):

Try this with XML :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center" >

   <ImageView 
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Output :

[image: Result]

Answer (score 0):

Where do you embed your imageview in xml? You parent layout needs width and height width match_parent.

If so, your image view needs the attribute layout_gravity="center". This should work in xml.

Answer (score 0):

First take RelativeLayout and then add rule to it. And Imageview set inside it. Like below.

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = 
(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams)myButton.getLayoutParams();
layoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_IN_PARENT);
image.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
```

Answer (score 0):

you could do like this :

```
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams myLayout = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
        LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        myLayout.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;
        imageView.setLayoutParams(myLayout);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:
        The xml code is

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout"
       >
    </RelativeLayout>
```

And in Class file try this:

```
   RelativeLayout layout=(RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.relativeLayout);
        ImageView imageView=new ImageView(this);
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params=new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        params.width=200;
        params.height=200;
        params.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_IN_PARENT);
        imageView.setLayoutParams(params);
        imageView.setImageResource(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
        layout.addView(imageView);
```